# Configuration of a NIC from a Linux Bash Shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, networking, ip

I have a Dell laptop running the following version of RedHat Linux:
2.6.18-53.el5 #1 SMP Wed Oct 10 16:34:02 EDT 2007 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux

It has an Ethernet-over-USB connection to a device under test (DUT). This interface to the DUT is usually configured as follows:
IP address: 104.4.40.2
Netmask: 255.255.255.0
Default gateway: 104.4.40.1

The default gateway points to the DUT.

Occasionally, I need to change the IP address / default gateway to 104.4.20.2 and 104.4.20.1, respectively. (The netmask remains 255.255.255.0).

I need to make this change when I load a new configuration onto the DUT that changes its IP address. (This configuration loading is done over a second interface that is unrelated to the interface I'm discussing here.)

When I make the corresponding change to the Linux box's network configuration using the GUI, everything works fine. But I often work remotely by shelling in via ssh. So, all I have available in that case is a Bash shell.

I've used command "ifconfig" (to set the IP address and netmask) and command "route" (to install the default gateway forwarding entry) to reconfigure the interface, and I then used "iconfig" to bring the interface down and back up to try to get the changes to "take".

When I check the interface settings with "ifconfig", they looks right. When I check the forwarding table with "route", everything looks good (including the default gateway). Yet, when I try to ping the DUT, I get no reponse. If I configure the interface yet again using the GUI, I can then ping the DUT.

I am clearly doing something wrong. Could someone please kindly show me the Bash shell command line commands I need to issue to change the IP address and default gateway of interface "eth1"?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If I've got you right, you need these two simple commands:

```
vim /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth1            //modify the configuration
service network restart
```

Also you can write a primitive bash/perl/python wrapper for your routines...

[This answer](http://nixcraft.com/showthread.php/3088-How-do-I-configure-the-network-card-from-the-command-line) may be useful for you too.